# embed for a ping command on discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a nice looking ping command, with the message with the ping being an embed like this:

[image: example]

However, I don't want the embed to be edited. I want it to be sent as a **separate** message after the ping finished.

Here's my code:

```js
module.exports = {
 name: 'ping',
 description: "shows the bot/'s ping",
 execute(message, args, embed) {
  message.channel.send('**The Ping-inator!**\nPinging...').then((msg) => {
   var ping = msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp;
   msg.edit("**The Ping-inator!**\nPong! bot's ping is `" + ping + 'ms`.');
  });
 },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit the message and hide the edited tag. It will appear on every edited message, whether it is sent from a bot or a user.

What you can do is, instead of editing the message, you can delete the old message and send a new one. This way, no edited tag will appear.

---

Here's a simple example I made:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.author.bot) return false;

 const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription('Checking the ping...')
  .setColor('#4287f5');
 message.channel.send(Embed).then((embedMessage) => {
  setTimeout(async () => {
   Embed.setDescription('Pong! The ping is `2000ms`!');
   await embedMessage.delete().catch((error) => console.log(error));
   message.channel.send(Embed);
  }, 2000);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to edit it, just send another message.

```js
message.channel.send('**The Ping-inator!**\nPinging...').then((msg) => {
 ping = msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp;
 const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor(`RANDOM`)
  .setTitle(`Ping`)
  .setDescription(
   "**The Ping-inator!**\nPong! bot's ping is `" + ping + 'ms`.'
  );
 message.channel.send(embed);
 msg.delete();
});
```

Comment: i needed an embed,like ive shown above in a imgur link..

Comment: That's really simple dude. This entire command is really simple

Comment: Nonetheless, I have edited my answer to make an embed (again, this is really simple, if you knew javascript and discord.js you wouldn't need our help)